# How do I access a DSE cluster from an app running in a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, datastax-enterprise

I have a provided Cassandra Database installation on a server.

On the other hand my customer has a Kubernetes Cluster with a deployed application that needs to connect to the database and we expirience the following error when the container tries to start up.

```
WARN  [com.dat.oss.dri.int.cor.con.ControlConnection] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) [s0] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=cassandra:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=379c44fa), trying next node (UnknownHostException: cassandra: Temporary failure in name resolution)
```

An suggestions what I am missing or what I need to do in my cluster?

Comment: Please provide complete information. The details of your cassandra setup, the details of the setup configuration in your customer cluster. Is it being deployed in a k8s cluster? If so, what is the `deployment` file? Is cassandra also deployed in k8s? Same cluster? Different cluster?

Comment: The cassandra DB is neither deploxed in a container nor in k8s, it is installed on bare metal

Comment: Do you have DNS setup where the Cassandra service is available to the k8s cluster through a DNS name `cassandra`? Since this is an outside component, k8s relies on your external DNS resolution to discover this service.

Comment: If not, you have to determine your service URL, like `1.2.3.4:1234/some_endpoint` and provide this to your k8s application, which will connect with it directly.

Comment: Notice it is attempting to connect to a URL `cassandra:9042`. This means k8s should be able to resolve the hostname `cassandra` somehow, internally or externally.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have DNS setup where the Cassandra service is available to the k8s cluster through a DNS name cassandra? Since this is an outside component, k8s relies on your external DNS resolution to discover this service.

Notice it is attempting to connect to a URL cassandra:9042. This means k8s should be able to resolve the hostname cassandra somehow, internally or externally.

If not, you have to determine your service URL, like `<some-IP>:<some-Port>/some_endpoint` and provide this to your k8s application, which will connect with it directly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you haven't configured the correct contact points in your application. In the error you posted, your application is connecting to an unknown host `cassandra`:

```
... Error connecting to Node(endPoint=cassandra:9042, ...
```

but your app doesn't know how to resolve the hostname `cassandra` leading to:

```
UnknownHostException: cassandra: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

We recommend that you specify at least two IP addresses of nodes in the "local DC" as contact points. For example if you're using the Java driver to connect to your Cassandra cluster, configure the contact points with:

```
datastax-java-driver {
  basic {
    contact-points = [ "node_IP1:9042", "node_IP2:9042" ]
  }
}
```

Since your application is running in Kubernetes, you'll need to make sure that it has network connectivity to your Cassandra cluster. Cheers!